# How to connect MSSQL in Laravel homestead?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, homestead

I am trying to connect with a MSSQL database using laravel homestead. It always throws the exception:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: could not find driver.

I've seen a lot of people talking about FreeTDS and Sybase drivers, but I can't seem to figure out what I need to enable laravel/php access to MSSQL databases from a Linux Web Server running the Laravel Homestead Vagrant box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did lots of R&D for resolving this issue. Finally found the solution:

Laravel vagrant is using php 7.  For mssql support we have to enable the relevant sybase driver for linux :

#### To Enable MSSQL Support for PHP 7:

First, ssh into your box vagrant ssh from the Homestead folder.

Command : `vagrant ssh`

Install the Sybase package for enabling the support for PDO and Mssql.

Command : `sudo apt-get install php7.0-sybase`

then run `php -m` on the ssh to make sure *pdo_dblib* is enabled.

All Done!!!! Cheers

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Install works fine, but pdo_dblib is not enabled.

Comment: Update: oficial docs from Microsoft to install mssql server on Ubuntu: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

The following works for php72. You may try changing the version of php in the commands.

```
vagrant ssh

#set the default PHP version to 7.2
php72

sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -

#Download appropriate package for the OS version
#Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

#Ubuntu 16.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Ubuntu 18.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

#Ubuntu 20.04
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17

sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

sudo pecl config-set php_ini /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
sudo pecl install sqlsrv
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
sudo su
printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
exit
sudo phpenmod -v 7.2 sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm

# restart nginx, if needed:
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

References:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu17
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-the-drivers-on-ubuntu-1604-1804-and-2004

Comment: Latest update: pecl/sqlsrv now requires PHP (version >= 7.4.0). Therefore, please use php 7.4 version minimum. In the above script, change 7.2 to 7.4 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses PDO extension to connect to database, you could check if the extension is enabled using

```
var_dump(class_exists('PDO'))
```

Also, if you could post the specific error, it would be great.

Comment: Although, Homestead should have the PDO enabled.

Comment: var_dump (class_exists('PDO')) is resulting : /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php:22:boolean true

Comment: PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
could not find driver
in Connector.php line 55
at PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=192.168.1.10\sql2014;Database=unvmc_siam', 'sa', 'FGG', array('0', '2', '0', false)) in Connector.php line 55

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. Still works as of now with:

1. php7.2-sybase
2. using DB_HOST= IP_ADDRESS\NAMED_INSTANCE
3. Commenting out the PORT directive in both .env and database.php